# Add a ListViewItem to multiple groups

Tags: c#, listview, grouping, listviewitem

I'm trying to add all Items of a ListView to groups, so that an item can be in multiple groups.
Items in the ListView correspond to a List where Something has a member called Genre which is a List so an item can have multiple genres.
I want to make groups for every Genre present in the list and make all items be in their respective groups.
I wanted to make a thing like that :

```
ListView1.Items.All(x => { x.Groups.Add("groupname"); x.Groups.Add("groupname 2"); return true; });
```

Is it possible or do I have to make my own ListView ?

Comment: It is not possible.  Each Item includes a reference to the Group it is a member of: `ListViewItem.Group` which means they can belong to only one group.  The answer provided simply creates extra items in order to assign them to all groups.  This will work if the redundant data doesnt annoy you or the user and you wont have to reconcile changes later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it work for me

```
listView1.Columns.Add("Col1");
listView1.Columns.Add("Col2");

string[] strArrGroups = new string[3] { "FIRST", "SECOND", "THIRD" };
string[] strArrItems = new string[4] { "uno", "dos", "twa", "quad" };
for (int i = 0; i < strArrGroups.Length; i++)
 {
    int groupIndex = listView1.Groups.Add(new ListViewGroup(strArrGroups[i],HorizontalAlignment.Left));
for (int j = 0; j < strArrItems.Length; j++)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(strArrItems[j]);
    lvi.SubItems.Add("Hasta la Vista, Mon Cherri!");
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    listView1.Groups[i].Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

}